# Received verbal job offer and still waiting on written offer; recruiter stopped responding? Should I call or email again?

Tags: job-offer, recruitment

After a long interview process with Microsoft, I received a verbal offer from the recruiter.  I did not negotiate the salary, and agreed with the company that I would sign.  Ever since then the recruiter and I have had a few back and forth emails about when I would receive my written offer.  It has been 3-4 weeks and I still don't have the offer.

I have separate emails from my recruiter mentioning "welcome to the company," "the Marketing Officer is excited for your onboarding," and "you will most likely start mid-Feb we are trying to work out training schedules."  Every email from the recruiter says that I will have the written offer by the end of the week (or end of next week), and still no offer letter.  My recruiter said that the delays is due to a new process that the company is still not used to.

Recently, I've sent 2 emails and a Skype Message (just updating the recruiter of my new address since I moved locations for the job already and to get updates), and the recruiter hasn't responded.  It has been a week since the last 2 emails.  Maybe the recruiter is just busy.  **Should I email again? Just call him directly? or just wait longer?**

Need some advice please?!? (been a month since I got the verbal offer)

Comment: Is this an internal recruiter from Microsoft, or is this some external company working as an intermediary? Have you tried contacting the Microsoft office you are supposed to start working directly and ask for an HR contact?

Comment: This is an internal recruiter from Microsoft. I have the person's contact information

Comment: Maybe the recruiter went on holidays or is out sick?

Comment: Verbal talk-talk means ***nothing***.  This is always true, in all times, in all places, in this universe.    Verbal talk-talk means ***nothing***.

Comment: In my company the "verbal offer" is enough. I mean, I waited for 3 days for an email worrying about what happened, so I've called to HR and they told me about this

Comment: Call is way better than emails and messages

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p)

Answer (score 8):

A "verbal" offer is not an offer, you are not employed until the contract is signed.  You should not have stopped looking for a job in the first place, but that's a sunk cost so no use in rehashing it.

As for what you should do now: Start looking for a new, new job.  No use in waiting for a job offer which may never come; if it's already been a month and you don't have the offer letter, then you have no idea when it will come, if at all.  If you get a new job in the meantime, then when/if the offer from Microsoft eventually comes, you can choose what to do then.  In the meantime, paying the bills is important and you should get that taken care of first and foremost.

Answer (score 4):

To directly answer your question "Should I email again? Just call him directly? or just wait longer?"

Given that you have characterized the situation thusly:

> "I have separate emails from my recruiter mentioning "welcome to the company," "the Marketing Officer is excited for your onboarding," and "you will most likely start mid-Feb we are trying to work out training schedules.""

Do one of these two things -

1. If you are anyway in the same city as Recruiter, at this time (like, 9:12AM PST Wednesday) go to the office, en route send a text and email to Recruiter mentioning that you will be in the office at 930 if they have 2 minutes to talk to you,

or

2. If not in the same city, use phone now

Good luck!